# DAO: dbSeeChanges alters behavior of FindFirst method of Recordset object

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao, jet

Recently I needed to add the parameter dbSeeChanges to the OpenRecordset method of the Database object in order to prepare the system for SQL Server progressive migration.

The thing is that change seemingly altered the functioning of the Recordset object in the following way.

Previously, if I had a Recordset that returned no records and I used the FindFirst method it went smoothly without errors, it simply found nothing and moved on. But now, in this same scenario, that action raises the following runtime error: 3021 "No current record".

Given a recordset with that returns no records the following code runs without errors:

```
Dim dbCurrDB As Dao.Database
Dim rstA As Recordset

Set dbCurrDB = CurrentDB
Set rstA = dbCurrDB.OpenRecordset("SomeTable", dbOpenDynaset)

With rst

  .FindFirst "Id=1"

  If .NoMatch=False Then

    .Edit
      !SomeField=SomeValue
    .Uptade

  End If

End With
```

Given the same conditions, the following code raises that 3021 error on the '.FindFirst "Id=1"' instruction:

```
Dim dbCurrDB As Dao.Database
Dim rstA As Recordset

Set dbCurrDB = CurrentDB
Set rstA = dbCurrDB.OpenRecordset("SomeTable", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

With rst

  .FindFirst "Id=1"

  If .NoMatch=False Then

    .Edit
      !SomeField=SomeValue
    .Uptade

  End If

End With
```

I know how to solve the issue (although it will finally force me to correct all legacy...). What I want is to understand why this happens. What exactly did change? Something with the pointer of the Recordset object? And also, if there can be other unintended side effects.

I wonder if there are some detailed technical specifications for DAO that can show me what the heck really happens with the mehods of the Recordset object behind the scenes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unrelated to the error, but since you are opening a recordset, why don't you filter it directly to the required id instead of opening the whole table and then searching for the id?

Comment: @Kostas K. Imagine you have a ton of temp tables you create and destroy in sompe process and then you need to traverse the records in that table to do some stuff. You can create a tone of parametrized queries, but this way it's simpler. But, mainly, because it's legacy and a lot of things could be drastically optimized. But you know, the codebase is gigantic and time is scarce.

Comment: Interesting observation... I never noticed that. But as Gustav wrote, after opening a potential empty recordset, the first thing to check should always be `.EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

Check for records, or there is nothing to find:

```vb
With rst
    If .RecordCount > 0 Then
        .FindFirst "Id=1"
        If .NoMatch = False Then
            .Edit
                !SomeField.Value = SomeValue
            .Update
        End If
    End If
    .Close
End With
```

Comment: yea, I know how to avoid it. Or I could check the EOF property. But what I'm trying is to understand why this happens, why the change in the parameter causes this change in behaviour.

Comment: I don't know. I always check for records as, in my experience, _FindFirst_ always fails on an empty recordset.